# How to center 2 rows of 2 images with text underneath each image

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm trying to make something like this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

(can't paste the image due to 2 missing points of reputation ;) ) https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7xhr.jpg

I'm sorry I've given an impression like I don't know what I'm doing at all and I want someone else to do my work for me. I did try various solutions none of which seems to work.

on jfsfiddle it seems to work, but when I check on the actual site the top right image gets moved to another row

http://jsfiddle.net/37GAn/1/

html

```
<div>
  <div class="image">
  <img src="image.jpg" width="98" height="203"/>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
  <img src="image.jpg" width="85" height="203"/>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="image.jpg" width="130" height="210"/>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="image.jpg" width="69" height="197"/>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.image {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:280px;
}
```

Comment: Start it with http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web

Comment: If you do not know where to start you may need to learn HTML and CSS is a bit more before getting started. This is pretty simple but SO is more for question and help an existing struggle.

Comment: edited now to explain i do indeed in theory know multiple solutions to this problem, none of which seems to work in this case. The one here is working on jsfiddle, but when you look on the actual site the top right image gets misaligned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just to give you a round-about idea.

You'll need your HTML as such:

```
<div id="contentHolder">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="textHolder">Some text here</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="textHolder">Some text here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="textHolder">Some text here</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="textHolder">Some text here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS as such:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#contentHolder {
    background-color:Gray;
    height:100%;
    padding:40px 10px;
}
.row {
    height:250px;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
.row > div {
    display:inline-block;
    width:48%;

    height:inherit;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.image {
    background:white url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png) no-repeat 0px 0px scroll;
    height:160px;
    width:70%;
    margin:20px auto;
    border-radius:10px;
}
.textHolder {
    color:White;
    width:50%;
    height:20px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

This should work for you. This may still need some work as I have not tried to make it inch-perfect. That I'll leave it to you!!! :)

You can see that here:http://jsfiddle.net/a7zLW/

Hope this helps!!!